# Do you need a server for Endpoint Antivirus Protection?

Tags: security, anti-virus, client-server

Ii'm looking into a few antivirus software packages for a small business with no more than 5 computers. Stumbled across endpoint protection, but was wondering if you needed a server to deploy this? The website didn't specify this as a requirement. And I'm aware of the client server architecture involved with this so really is there any way to just use this on the clients? Just need to find out before I buy.

Comment: So you can just use endpoint protection on the client computers alone? I'm running windows 10 on all computers, but am not happy with reviews on windows Defender and microsoft's AV history

Comment: I don't recall mentioning anything about McAfee buddy, but thanks for the heads up (Y)

Comment: It might help if you post the product Name you are asking questions about.